# How to convert a character to an integer in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

I am trying to simply convert a character or string to an integer in Swift 3. I am a long time C++ developer who is just learning Swift and finding it extremely frustrating to do some of the simplest things in Swift 3 (ie, indexing into a string, converting a character to an int).

Can someone please help me convert characters to ints, specifically in Swift 3 Xcode 8?

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate as some casting rules have changed since Swift 2.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as simple as this.

```
let myString = "5"
let sum = 3 +  Int(myString)!  // Produces 8
print(Int(myString)!)
```

Indexing

```
let str = "My test String Index"
let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)
str[index] // Returns e from test

let endIndex = str.index(str.endIndex, offsetBy:-2)
str[Range(index ..< endIndex)] // returns String "est String Ind"

str.substring(from: index) // returns String "est String Index"
str.substring(to: index) // returns String "My t"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let string = "1"
if let integer = Int(string) {
    print(integer)
}
```